# React : TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel-loader

By continuing my project for studying react js I ran into a new error that

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

I looked everywhere but I can't find a solution for this error this is my PokemonsContainer.js file

```
import React from "react";
import useQuery from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import {GET_POKEMONS}  from "../graphql/get-pokemons";
import { Pokemon } from "../components/Pokemon";


 function PokemonsContainer() {
    const { data: { pokemons = [] } = {} } = useQuery(GET_POKEMONS, { variables: { first: 9 },});
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            {pokemons && pokemons.map(pokemon => <Pokemon key={pokemon.id} pokemon={pokemon} />)}
        </div>
    );
}
export default PokemonsContainer
```

the error is showing on line 8 `const { data: { pokemons = [] } = {} } = useQuery(GET_POKEMONS, { variables: { first: 9 },});`

this is the query file get-pokemons.js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const GET_POKEMONS =gql`
    query pokemons($first: Int!){
        pokemons(first:$first){
            id
            name
            image
            maxHP
            maxCP
            attacks{
                special{
                    name
                    damage
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

here is Pokemon.js

```
import React from 'react';

export function Pokemon({ pokemon }) {
    return (<p>{pokemon.name}</p>)
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the Pokemon component?

Comment: Are you sure "@apollo/react-hooks" default exports a function, which is what you are calling "useQuery"? Didn't you mean `import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";`?

Comment: thanks you it was my mistake